# not debugging javascript code in firebug fire the error otherwise works perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I am sure this question seem silly to many of you 
but it really happen for me,
the code I shared below works perfectly when I debug it thoroughly in firebug
if not, and just running the code without debugging it raise an error,

```js
function edit(Barcode) {
  $('#pnlSize').show('fast');
  if ($('#test2 option').size() < 2) {
    $.ajax({

      url: '@Url.Action("selectedItemChanged")',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        barcode: Barcode
      },
      success: function(sizes) {

        var options = '<option value="Z">سایز را انتخاب کنید</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
          console.log(sizes);
          options += '<option value="' + sizes[i].ID + '">' + sizes[i].Size + '</option>';
        }
        $("#test2").html(options);
      }

    });
  }
  var val = $('#test2 :selected').text();
  if (val != 'سایز را انتخاب کنید' && val != null) {

    location.href = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart")?Barcode=' + Barcode + '&size=' + $('#test2 :selected').text();;

  }
}
```

the reason is that when do not debug it, it tries to run this :

```js
 location.href = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart")?Barcode=' + Barcode + '&size=' + $('#test2 :selected').text();;
```

but as dropdown has not being filled yet and user has not chosen any size, so addtoCart return null.

Please kindly help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that code inside your success function or add a timer to wait until the success call has completed. The success callback is firing after the rest of your code runs which is why your addtoCart is null.